# TouchTargetSizeCheck is not working with espresso while implementing Accessibility automation

Tags: android, android-espresso, accessibility

I'm working on a sample of Accessibility with espresso UI tests. To implement accessibility checks with UI test, I'm using [ATF](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/a11y-testing-espresso) (Accessibility Test Framework).

While running the test case with accessibility check, it doesn't show all the accessibility errors. In the sample below it should throw `TouchTargetSizeCheck` error. But in my case, it is getting compiled successfully.

Lib reference

> androidTestImplementation
> 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
> androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.4.0'

> MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
        var count = 0
        binding.tvCount.text = count.toString()

        binding.btnIncrement.setOnClickListener {
            count++
            binding.tvCount.text = count.toString()
        }
        binding.btnDecrement.setOnClickListener {
            count--
            binding.tvCount.text = count.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AccessibilityAutomation.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AccessibilityAutomation.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnDecrement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCount"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="0" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btnIncrement"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> MainActivityTest.kt

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class MainActivityTest {
    @get:Rule
    var activityScenarioRule: ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity> =
        ActivityScenarioRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    init {
        AccessibilityChecks.enable().setRunChecksFromRootView(true)
    }

    @Test
    fun testIncrement() {
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.btnIncrement))
            .perform(ViewActions.click())
        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.tvCount))
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(withText("1")))
    }

}
```

`TouchTargetSizeCheck` error is expected while running the UI test.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get other ATF errors? At first glance, I'm not sure that the AccessibilityChecks are getting stood up before the test runs, so it just isn't running any of the checks. What happens if you add the `@Before` tag above the `init`, or moved the `init` to a specific Setup method (with the `@Before` tag)?

Comment: @agoff Tried with Before block, still having the same issue

Comment: Are you seeing any ATF errors during test execution?

Comment: @agoff Yes, If we don't add a content description, it shows an error for label missing. But apart from the label missing, it doesn't capture any other error.

Comment: Does it work if you change TextView to a Button? It looks like the views should be clickable for this check, which setting onClickListener does, but maybe it doesn't happen in time for the test framework to pick it up https://github.com/google/Accessibility-Test-Framework-for-Android/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/accessibility/framework/checks/TouchTargetSizeCheck.java

Comment: @sigute Tried with Button, it has the same issue.